# How to create a VIEW from function with parameters?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I have this function in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(a integer, b timestamp, c integer[])
  RETURNS SETOF typ_new AS 
$BODY$
declare
begin
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW newView as (select * from func2($1,$2,$3));
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

`func2` also returns `SETOF typ_new` so they are compatible.

When running it I get an error : `ERROR:  there is no parameter $1`
if I change the `$1` to the parameter name `a` then the error changes to 
`ERROR: column "a" does not exist`

I also tried dynamic SQL:

```
    sqlstr ='CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW newView (columns... ) as
              (select * from func2('||$1||','||$2||','||$3||'))';
    execute sqlstr;
```

but it doesn't work because `$3` is `integer[]` and `||` can't work with arrays.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to do dynamic SQL; take a look at PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE` and the `format` parameter. See many related answers for details.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to create `VIEW as $BODY$` and make function select from this view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(a integer, b timestamp, c integer[]) RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW newView AS ' ||
            'SELECT * FROM func2(' || $1 || ', ' || $2 || ', ' || array_to_string($3, ',') || ')';
  RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Note that this function returns `void`, not `SETOF typ_new`, as you are creating a view, not returning data from the view.

Since `func2()` returns `typ_new` you do not have to explicitly declare the columns of the view, they will be taken from the `SELECT` statement: the elements of the `typ_new` type.

Comment: Use `format` with the `%L` format specifier instead of your concatenation and your `array_to_string` call. Cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure. but if you just want to pass array to dynamic sql string, you can mock it up?..

```
do
$$
declare 
  a integer[];
begin
  a := array[11,22,33,22,11];
  raise info '%','you can mock up array in like this: array['||array_to_string(a,',')||']';

end;

$$
;
```

I your case would be like:

```
 sqlstr ='CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW newView (columns... ) as
              (select * from func2('||$1||','||$2||',array['||array_to_string($3,',')||']))';
    execute sqlstr;
```